# Rails namespacing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this in my `config/routed.db`:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
  resources :events
end
```

I generated the `User` model by using the scaffolding Rails provides, then I simply generated a admin/admin controller by using Rails' `generate` and simply moved all the user-related stuff into the admin sub-directories inside the controllers/views/helpers. Yes, I did have to add `admin_` in a few places and inside the form partial I had to change the `form_for(@user)` to `form_for([:admin, @user])`.

When I try to create a new user (this is when I `POST` the user data) I get the following error message:

```
undefined method `user_url' for #<Admin::UsersController:0x13f408e0>
```

The application-level trace shows that the error is raised here:

```
app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:47:in `create'
```

The line of code where this error is raised:

```
format.html { redirect_to @user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.' }
```

The above line is inside the `respond_to` block.

So, I have two questions:

1. How do I fix this issue?
2. Is there a smarter, better, rails-way of doing this?

---

Also, bonus points if you suggest I re-do this in the *smarter, better, rails-way*! Well, I will do that anyway! :D

---

### Update

Oh, I almost forgot something that might be relevant! I also made `Admin::UsersController` inherit from `Admin::AdminController` (which normally in turn inherits from `ApplicationController`):

`Admin::UsersController < Admin::AdminController`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the namespace in your redirect, too:

```
redirect_to [:admin, @user] #...
```

or

```
redirect_to admin_user_path(@user) #...
```

Comment: Ok, this did fix the problem I was having. However, there were more similar ones, so I had to update a few more things in a similar manner, too. Is there maybe a the-right-rails-way to do this? I am not really sure what to look for, to be honest. My Rails terminology is very fundamental!

Comment: Not really - if you're using namespaces, then you need to make sure all the routes used in the controllers and views refer to that namespace where required.

Comment: Damn it! Well, thank you a lot for helping! Also, is there some reference-list where one can find the naming conventions, like the `admin_user_path` one you conjured?

Comment: You can find the concrete routes with `rake routes`. Other than that, take a look at [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).