# create new devise user from another non devise controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users table (Devise) , with a column "admin" (boolean) to qualify my users.
I also have a namespace "Backend". 
I would like that my admins users can create new users from the backend namespace.

So I created a `Backend::UsersController` :

```
class Backend::UsersController < ApplicationController
layout 'admin'
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index
@auteurs = User.all

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @auteurs }
  end
end

def new
 @auteur = User.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @auteur }
  end
end

def create
  @auteur = User.new(params[:auteur])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @auteur.save
      format.html { redirect_to @auteur, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @auteur, status: :created, location: @auteur }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @auteur.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
end
```

Here's the "_form" partial called in the "new" view :

```
<%= simple_form_for(@auteur) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

An here's my routes :

```
 namespace :backend do 
    resources :articles 
    root to: "articles#index"
    resources :accueil
resources :users

get "users/index"


    get "users/create"

    get "users/new"
 end

  devise_for :users
```

But when I try to access to "backend/users/new", it drives me to this error :

```
NoMethodError in Backend/users#new

Showing C:/Ruby/acturevue/app/views/backend/users/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x39616b0>:0x416f6d0>
```

Does somebody have any ideas of the source of the problem ?
Thanks

**UPDATE**

So, I modified my code like that :

In Backend::UsersController :

```
def new
   @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user}
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to backend_users_path(@user), notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In _form :

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

But I still have the error. 
However the backend_users_path exists in y routes :

```
            backend_users GET    /backend/users(.:format)             backend/users#
index
                      POST   /backend/users(.:format)             backend/users#
create
     new_backend_user GET    /backend/users/new(.:format)         backend/users#
new
    edit_backend_user GET    /backend/users/:id/edit(.:format)    backend/users#
edit
         backend_user GET    /backend/users/:id(.:format)         backend/users#
show
                      PUT    /backend/users/:id(.:format)         backend/users#
update
                      DELETE /backend/users/:id(.:format)         backend/users#
destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the namespace in your redirect:

```
redirect_to [:backend, @auteur] #...
```

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224176/rails-namespacing-error/13224299#13224299).

Comment: Thank you for caring about my problem, but the error is still there... I'll update my post to show you the modifications I did.

Comment: Thanks Thilo, it works ! I modified the _form partial with `simpleform_fom_for([:backend, @user])` and it's good.